# How to get data from DataTransfer.getData in event Dragover or Dragenter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui

I have a code to set data in dragstart:

```js
element.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
   e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', 'something is here');
}, false);
```

When I get data from `DataTransfer.getData` in event Drop, it works.
But when I want get to data in the dragover or dragenter events, data is null.

```js
element.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
   var a = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
   console.log(a);
}, false);
```

So, how to get the data in event dragover or dragenter?

Answer (score 37):

Normally you don't have access to this information on events other than `dragstart` and `drop`. Firefox seems to give you access but it seems to go against the standard.

The way the data is transfered during a drag and drop is through a `data store` object, that contains all the information needed for the different operations to happen. But there are certain restrictions to what you can do with this information depending on the `event` on which you access this data store. There are 3 modes, that are defined as follow:

> A drag data store mode, which is one of the following:
>
> **Read/write mode**
>
> For the dragstart event. New data can be added to the drag data store.
>
> **Read-only mode**
>
> For the drop event. The list of items representing dragged data can be
>   read, including the data. No new data can be added.
>
> **Protected mode**
>
> For all other events. The formats and kinds in the drag data store
>   list of items representing dragged data can be enumerated, but the
>   data itself is unavailable and no new data can be added.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-drag-data-store

So on dragover, the data store is in protected mode, hence the data shouldn't be available. Again, Firefox implements this differently, but you shouldn't rely on it in any case.

These modes are there for security reasons, these data transfer allows transfer not only of elements of a same page, but of data from other applications, files, etc.

Comment: It's a shame this is the case; it makes drawing placeholders and knowing what `dataTransfer.dropEffect` should be quite difficult if you don't know what it is that's being dragged.

Comment: If you control the dragstart, then you have access. If you don't, then it kind of makes sense to restrict what you can know, else you could have access to what's being dragged over your page without the user knowing.

Comment: To do a cross-window drag from page A to some arbitrary page B within the same domain, we don't have access to the dragstart from the drop-target page, which is rough. Alternatives?: pass messages (but we don't know the target page URL...just the domain), include some stringly-typed info in the `dataTransfer.types` field, or coordinate asynchronously with the server between the two pages.

Comment: ```dataTransfer.types``` indeed helps to identify what type of data is currently present on the dragged object. So if you added some data on 'dragstart' you could check what type of data it is in 'dragover'. Obviously you could 'hack' this and store your whole stringified information there too if you absolutely need to.

Comment: Would make sense to have this info when dragging within the same document though

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var dragged = undefined;

element.addEventListener('dragstart', function () {
    dragged = this;
});

element.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
    dragged = undefined;
});

element.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) {
    //e.g.
    if (dragged.classList.contains('list-item')) {
        // do something   
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this won't work across websites. Good suggestion, though, I will use a similar approach in my Electron app.